# Google Cloud Storage 429 PATCH Too many requests

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage, django-storage

I'm sorry if this isn't the place to ask, desperately looking for advice.

We have a Django 2.2 project using django-storages and GCS for a long time, about an hour ago we started to receive this error constantly, apparently, there is a rate of 1 per second, per file, however only one upload is being made, also we haven't deployed new code related to this, every section of our site where user uploads file we get this error.

We don't consume directly the API, we only execute "save" on our models.

Any ideas on how can we debug this?
This is an example of a complete error:
429 PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/at_private_storage/o/dany8%2Fdocumentos%2Faaa16962-fe3e-4242-b479-12d4d4d84ea7.xml?projection=full&predefinedAcl=publicRead: The rate of change requests to the object at_private_storage/dany8/documentos/aaa16962-fe3e-4242-b479-12d4d4d84ea7.xml exceeds the rate limit. Please reduce the rate of create, update, and delete requests.

Comment: I've started seeing the same thing just now. After we upload a file we execute a "make_public" on the blob, and it's returning this error. I think we just have to put a delay in.

Comment: @Mark try updating django-storages python package.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - However we aren't using django. I'll take a look at the django-storages changelog.

Answer (score 0):

We updated django-storages from 1.7.1 1.9.1 and apparently problem is solved.